# Aggregate and keep non-aggregated fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have some data that is composed of several item types and for each item type, there are different items and the name of the items is unique.

I was considering having a collection in MongoDB like

```json
{
  id: 0,
  itemType1: {
    item1: {
      value: 1,
      units: "unit",
    },
    item2: {
      value: 3,
      units: "unit",
    },
  },
  itemType2: {
    item3: {
      value: 2,
      units: "unit",
    },
    item4: {
      value: [1, 2, 3],
      labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    },
  },
  ...
  itemType11: {
    item55: {
      value: 5,
      units: "unit",
    },
  },
  ...
},
```

I need to generate the following output, where I need to

1. Filter by a list of ids
2. Sum or average the values depending on the item
3. Keep the rest of the fields

```json
{
  itemType1: {
    item1: {
      sumValue: 3,
      units: "unit",
    },
    item2: {
      sumValue: 6,
      units: "unit",
    },
  },
  itemType2: {
    item3: {
      sumValue: 3,
      units: "unit",
    },
    item4: {
      sumValue: [5, 3, 6],
      labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    },
  },
  ...
  itemType11: {
    item55: {
      meanValue: 6,
      units: "unit",
    },
  },
}
```

- It is a good approach?
- How can I make a query that aggregates some fields and keep others as they are?

Comment: I sense the data model might work better if the doc had an array of items, with each member being a subdoc like `{itemType:1, value:1, units: "unit"}`.  You could later `$group` by the `itemType` and perform other array-based operations much easier.

Comment: your schema is complicated, you save data on keys, and that makes things hard(keys are for the schema not for data in general) also you have items nested to other items, and they have different schema, for example other have sumValue/units others have sumvalue/labels, in others sumValue is number in others its array. i think you need to make the schema much more simpler if possible, if one itemType has many items, those items are best to be in array also.

Comment: Maybe somehting like this? or you can make also each item a document
`[{id: 0,items : [{type type1  items [{values ...
 units ...
 labels ...},
 {values ...
  units ...
  labels ...},}]]}]`